# SAMBA -- Cannot access Samba share from XP

Tags: samba, windows-xp

Cannot access SAMBA share on Ubuntu 12.04 box from XP box.

SAMBA is up and running on the Ubuntu box. `smb.conf` has the correct windows workgroup name in it, and I can see the Ubuntu box from the XP machine.

On the Ubuntu box, I have set up a UNIX username `CCD1` with a password for the purposes of sharing. I have added a Samba username in Samba Server Configuration of `UNIX name: ccd1`, `Windows Username: Mike` (username on the XP box), and put in password (same as used for the UNIX username).

I have given access to the Samba shared folder for this username.

On the XP box I can browse the Network Neighborhood, drill down to the workgroup shares and see the Ubuntu box. I can see the shared folder on the Ubuntu box. It is also sharing printers. I can access the printers, I cannot access the shared folder.

Here is how /etc/samba/smb.conf lists the two shares:

```
[PRINT$]
  comment = all printers
  browseable = no
  path = var/spool/samba
  printable = yes
; guest ok = no
; read only = yes
  create mask = 6766

[CCD_Staff_Dailies]
  comment = Shared Folder
  path = /media/HDD 1/CCD/CCD_Staff_Dailies
  writeable = yes
; browseable = yes
  valid users = sysadmin, ccd1
```

If I attempt to view the contents of the shared folder from the XP box it doesn't ask for my credentials, I just get:

> \Ccd-files-linux\CCD_Staff_Dailies is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. Access is denied."

Comment: have you firewall enabled like ufw. It could block access. I had same message when ufw was enable and port was closed.

Comment: @Pat: It's a clean install of 12.04 and I have not configured `ufw` or `iptables` so the firewall is set up per install defaults. I can access that shared folder from another Ubuntu machine, and as mentioned, I can also access the print$ share from the XP machine.

Comment: the path is set to  path = `var/spool/samba`, maybe there is just a slash missing?

Comment: Keep in mind Samba changes which tighten security a bit - XP is probably not in mind with these security changes

Answer (score 14):

I just want to get into a public record that nowadays you need to add these configurations into the [Global] section of /etc/samba/smb.conf to make Windows XP able to connect to your Samba 4.5 server:

```
server max protocol = NT1
lanman auth = yes
ntlm auth = yes
```

Of course that compromises the security on some level I am deliberately unaware of.

Comment: "I found that without these lines Android 5.1.1 wasn't able to access the share neither. Samba version 4.5.8-Debian under Raspian 9" -BeeGee

Comment: In addition to the advice below on using min protocol and not max, I'd like to encourage anyone (anyone!?) bumping into this issue to first try insisting your XP box uses NTLM 2.0 before resorting to allowing "lanman auth" or "ntlm auth":
https://kb.iu.edu/d/atcm

XP with SP3 supports NTLM v2 for security but only SMB1 (aka NT1) for the actual sharing protocol.

Answer (score 11):

Just to update on the answer from @loop. I'd recommend using `min protocol = NT1` instead of `server max protocol = NT1` to allow other clients to use the more up-to-date and secure versions of SMB.

Answer (score 3):

For me it works:

Edit `/etc/samba/smb.cfg`.

Add the following at beginning (global):

```
server min protocol = NT1
lanman auth = yes
ntlm auth = yes
```

NT1 is a old version of security: SMBv1... necessary for Windows XP!
The other 2 lines is necessary to make logon, if not, you cannot make login.